# Web Parts and HTML pages

Tags: html, asp.net

Is every web part encapsulated in its own html page?

Say we have one root page, called index.html

within index.html, lets say we have two web parts, A and B.

Will the web parts both belong to index.html, or will they have their separate html files, with essentially 3 different .html files (index, A, B)?

Comment: What's a "web part"?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, and it's hard to understand what you're referring to as 'web parts'.

Comment: A web part is a pretty old term - I think it mostly applies to SharePoint now. It used to refer to customizable areas of the page where you could drag and drop stuff (much like My Yahoo's interface). Is that what you're talking about, or do you mean usercontrols?

Answer (score 0):

Each .html / .htm page can have its own tags (eg. `body, ul, b` etc)

but if you have `a href="SomeFile.html"`, you will need a new HTML page